# How does I2C Protocol work

Tags: c, i2c, 8051

I have visited on some links and looked for some example programs for I2C programming.  I want to write my own code for I2C protocol. Suppose DS1307 RTC and LCD connected to 8051. I am using Keil software to write a C program. It's very difficult to write whole program of I2C for me, so I tried to break program in small parts:

- Module 1: define and set pins for LCD and DS1307 RTC
- Module 2: write C code for DS1307 (make functions for DS1307 such as read, write)
- Module 3: write C code for LCD (data, command initialize, etc)
- Module 4: main function

I understand module 1 but I am looking help to understand module 2. So again I want break module 2 in small parts.

How to break module 2 in small parts for easy understanding? How many functions should be in module2?

Comment: The 8051 itself doesn't include an I2C controller. There are many devices that has a 8051 together with other on-chip stuff, e.g. a I2C controller. What is your case? If your chip doesn't have a built-in I2C controller, you'll have to do bit-bang using the native 8051 ports. Try search the net for something like "8051 bit bang I2C". It will give you multiple code examples, e.g. https://www.8051projects.net/wiki/I2C_Implementation_on_8051 If your chip does include an I2C controller the data sheet will tell you how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Module 2 is essentially I2C driver using bit banging of 8051 port. I2C protocol follows a sequence. It is started by start sequence and stopped by stop sequence. You can have different functions. The communication is started by the master and each slave has an address. So in module2, you will write all below functions.

For example, the I2 read sequence will be following

```
I2C_Start();  // set I2C start sequence
I2C_Send(slave_address|1); Send I2C slave address in read mode
I2C_read_ACK(); //master will know slave got data 
while(number_of bytes){
I2C_Read();
I2C_send_ACK();
number_of bytes--;
}
I2C_NAK();    //slave need to know so it will not prepare next data.
I2C_Stop();   //stop communication
```

Again the write on slave will have below steps

```
I2C_Start();  // set I2C start sequence
I2C_Send(slave_address); Send I2C slave address in write mode
I2C_read_ACK(); //master will know slave got data 
while(number_of bytes){
I2C_Write();
I2C_read_ACK(); //master will know slave got data 
number_of bytes--;
}
I2C_Stop(); //stop communication
```

I also see driver at
https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/digital-clock-using-8051-microcontroller

Official I2C protocol is here

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwici4Ocn6jVAhUIwlQKHV_zAJ8QFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nxp.com%2Fdocuments%2Fuser_manual%2FUM10204.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHgNi6wOD4MjIDsnT0DXTYLS_-gPQ

Answer (score 0):

```
i2c protocol
```

```
void i2c_WriteByte(unsigned char Data)
{
  i2c_Start();
  i2c_Write(device_id);
  i2c_Write(register_address);
  i2c_Write(Data);
  i2c_Stop();
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?